# Regex - find all instances of words that begin with # but do not contain 'administrator'

Tags: regex

I am having a hard time getting my head around this regex.  What I am trying to do is as follows:

- Match any occurrence of words that begin with #.  So, for example, if the code finds the following tags #jon, #james, #jill, then it should hide the text.
- But if the code finds occurrences of the following tag: #ADMINISTRATOR, then it should display the text
- In addition, if the code finds no occurrences of any words tagged with #, it should also display the text.

Essentially, I want to hide any comments that are hashed tagged with a user name other than ADMINISTRATOR.

So far, I have the following code:

```
if (mb_ereg_match(".*(#[^ADMINISTRATOR]){1,}.*", $comment))
{
    $hideComment = true;
}else
{
    $hideComment = false;
}
```

The above code works for the most part, except for when the text being searched contains any one of the following:

```
#A, #AD, #ADM, #ADMI, #ADMIN, etc.
```

then the code does not hide the comment, which is not what I want.  I only want an exact match to '#ADMINISTRATOR' to display the comments.  Plus, any comment that contains no tags should also be displayed.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't put the `.*` at the beginning of the regex.  It does nothing for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [negative lookahead based regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that will work for you:

```
(?i)#(?!ADMINISTRATOR)\w+
```

Here is a [Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/rcsCxx3ANI)

Answer (score 1):

I've not used whatever program you're using to write your regex, but the syntax in general isn't doing what you think it is. When you use a set of [], you are saying that what lies within is a class of characters. Your regular expression states I'm looking for something that follows a #, but that something doesn't begin with an A, or any of the following characters.

What you want to use is another grouping. You can use () instead of [] to represent a specific group of characters. However, as you may notice, () is also what you use to capture part of your regex. Thus, you'll want to use a non-matching group. In python, non-matching groups look like this: (?:ADMINISTRATOR)

All put together, your regex might look something like this in python:

```
mb_ereg_match("(#.*(?!ADMINISTRATOR))\w ",$COMMENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

An interval in a regex will always match **a single character**, whether negated or not. `[ADMINISTRATOR]` will match either an `A`, `D`, `M` and so forth. `[^ADMINISTRATOR]` will match anything that is not an `A`, `D`, `M`, etc.

If you want a regex that does not have a given string, I'd suggest using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead, as anubhava [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505896/520779).